# Angular 2+: Opening Bootstrap modal through typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, ng-bootstrap

Typically, when opening a modal, the function is called through HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(content)">Launch demo modal</button>
```

which would open up the modal:

```
  <ng-template #content let-modal>
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Profile update</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dateOfBirth">Date of birth</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <input id="dateOfBirth" class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" ngbDatepicker #dp="ngbDatepicker">
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="dp.toggle()" type="button"></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close('Save click')">Save</button>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
```

However, due to circumstances (I'm using Google Charts and the HTML where I could use `(click) = "open(content"` isn't exposed to me), I need to be able to open the modal through javascript/typescript.

I attempted to do so like this:

```
  open(content) {

    this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'}).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }

  select(event: ChartSelectEvent) {

        this.open(content); //<--Attempt to Open Modal

        if ('deselect' === event.message) {    
        }
        else if ('select' === event.message) {

        }
      }
```

My attempt doesn't open up the modal.  So, I think that what I need to do is how to call a `template reference variable (#content)` through typescript but I'm not sure how

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a reference to the template with `@ViewChild("content")`:

```
@ViewChild("content") private contentRef: TemplateRef<Object>;
```

and use that variable to open the modal:

```
this.open(this.contentRef);
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rumqbo?file=app%2Fmodal-basic.ts) for a demo.

Comment: Damn, you beat me for the answer: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ay5p3z?file=app%2Fmodal-basic.ts